# Datatables Multi Filter Same Column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I need to be able to apply multiple filters to a single column using datatables.

I've been looking at an example they have provided [here](https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) but my requirements are slightly different.

The first column in my table will contain location information, each cell will contain a `building name` and `floor`. I want to have two dropdowns that allow users to filter on both of these.

So e.g. '*Show me Building 1 and Second Floor*'.

I can get the first dropdown to filter on building, but the second doesn't filter on floor.  My current code is below, here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/qubjohnny/pen/jOPrymJ?editors=1010).

Note I have simplified this table and limited it to 6 records, my live table will contain hundreds of records.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $("#example").DataTable();

  $("#dropdown1").on("change", function() {
    table
      .columns(0)
      .search(this.value)
      .draw();
  });
  $("#dropdown2").on("change", function() {
    table
      .columns(0)
      .search(this.value)
      .draw();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select id="dropdown1">
  <option value="">Building</option>
  <option value="Building 1">Building 1</option>
  <option value="Building 2">Building 2</option>
</select>
<select id="dropdown2">
  <option value="">Floor</option>
  <option value="First Floor">First Floor</option>
  <option value="Second Floor">Second Floor</option>
  <option value="Third Floor">Third Floor</option>
</select>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Building 1<br><span class="floor">First Floor</span></td>
      <td>Available</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Building 1<br><span class="floor">Second Floor</span></td>
      <td>Available</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Building 1<br><span class="floor">Third Floor</span></td>
      <td>Available</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Building 2<br><span class="floor">First Floor</span></td>
      <td>Unavailable</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Building 2<br><span class="floor">Second Floor</span></td>
      <td>Available</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Building 2<br><span class="floor">Third Floor</span></td>
      <td>Unavailable</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

Create an array of the select elements, join them with a space and send them as one search term. Think DT has more on regex on their docs.

```
<select class="filter_location" id="filter_building">
    <option value="">Building</option>
    <option value="Building 1">Building 1</option>
    <option value="Building 2">Building 2</option>
</select>

<select class="filter_location" id="filter_floor">
    <option value="First Floor">First Floor</option>
    <option value="Second Floor">Second Floor</option>
    <option value="Third Floor">Third Floor</option>
</select>

$('select.filter_location').on( 'change', function () {
    var val = [];
    val.push($('#filter_building').val());
    val.push($('#filter_floor').val());
    table.column(0).search(val.join(' ')).draw();
} );
```